# Saving NSMutableArray and loading it in a UITableView

Tags: xcode, sdk, nsmutablearray, save, tableview

I want to save multiple NSMutableArray and load it because this array gets it content from a server and i don't want to reload that data every time the app is opened.
First I declared the paths:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *firstPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"first"];
     NSString *secondPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"second"];
     NSString *thirdPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"third"];
     NSString *fourthPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fourth"];
```

then save the NSMutableArrays:

```
         [firstArray writeToFile:firstPath atomically:YES];
         [secondArray writeToFile:secondPath atomically:YES];
         [thirdArray writeToFile:thirdPath atomically:YES];
         [fourthArray writeToFile: fourthPath atomically:YES];
```

then open these files in other NSMutableArrays:

```
    firstArrayget = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:firstPath];
    secondArrayget = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:secondPath];
    thirdArrayget = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:thirdPath];
    fourthArrayget = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:fourthPath];
```

then I try to load these Arrays (...Arrayget i.e. firstArrayget) into a TableView.

The data gets loaded into the TableView, but when I scroll down the App crashes with the Error:

```
*** -[CFArray objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x930fc80
```

and in the file:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode=0x0)
```

but if I say the TableView to load the data from the (...Array i.e. firstArray),so the data downloaded from the server unsaved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using MRC and not ARC:
Looks like you're setting an ivar to an autoreleased `NSMutableArray`.
Try calling `retain`on the `NSMutableArray`s, otherwise your `NSMutableArray`s will just get released and thus deallocated when the autoreleasepool drains.
Another solution is to use a property for each of your `NSMutableArray`s like this:

```
// Create a property in your header file
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *firstArrayget;

// And set the property in your method
[self setFirstArrayGet:[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:firstPath]];
```

You can find more about Objective-C memory management at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html